# Why $Id:(\mathbb R^2,d_2)\to(\mathbb R^2,d_0)$ is open but not continuous.

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

Can someone please explain, step-by-step, the intuition behind why;

- $Id:(\mathbb R^2,d_2)\to(\mathbb R^2,d_0)$ is open but not continuous.

(I understand that every subset of $d_0$ is open etc, but I need help with the continuity part.)

- $f:(\mathbb R,d)\to (\mathbb R,d)$ given by $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous but not open.

I have the answers but not the method of getting to them.

I am aware this is probably a simple question, but I am struggling to get my head around the concept.
If someone could explain this to me I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

$\text{Id}$ is continuous at $x$ if $$\forall \epsilon>0 \exists \delta >0 : d_2(x,y)<\delta \implies d_0(x,y) < \epsilon. $$ If we consider $\epsilon\le 1$ then it must be

$$\exists \delta >0 : d_2(x,y)<\delta \implies d_0(x,y)=0. $$ This is clearly false  for $y\ne x.$ Thus, $Id$ is not continuous at any point.